# Bloquear acesso de pagina PHP pela URL | Duvida sobre segurança das mesmas

Tags: php, segurança

**DUVIDA 1**

No meu site tenho paginas PHP que fazem o cadastro/login de usuarios, produtos, e outras coisas, as quais eu chamo através do ajax. Tem alguma forma para não permitir que as pessoas acessem essas paginas via URL?

Exemplo: **meusite.com/conexao/cadastro.php**

**DUVIDA 2 | Relacionada com a primeira**

Para bloquear acesso de áreas restritas do site estou usando:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_logado'])){
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
```

Essa é a melhor maneira?

Se não é a melhor, pode ser considerada segura?

Poderia utilizar esse método para proteção de paginas citadas na DUVIDA 1?

Não haveria nenhum conflito com o ajax? já que a pessoa ainda não estaria logada

**DUVIDA 3**

Não sou muito experiente em PHP como gostaria, então me desculpem a ignorância, segundo oque sei, o conteúdo PHP de uma pagina não fica disponível para os usuários verem, como conexão com o BD, login e cadastro e outras, mas acredito que esse acesso seja possível por força bruta. Posso confiar na segurança própria PHP ou seria necessário fazer uma segurança adicional? Como consultado nas duas primeiras duvidas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se está sessão é estabelecida atráves de login e senha sim o acesso está seguro no entanto no seu código aonde faz o redirecionamento poderia enviar junto ao redirect um cabeçalho de resposta **HTTP status 403**´OU **HTTP STATUS 401**

> 403 Forbidden vs 401 Unauthorized HTTP responses ou seja (**não autorizado**)

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_logado'])){
     header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
     header("Location: index.php");
     exit;
}
```

Além disso em cada página php que se comunica com sua interface de gerencia é necessário verificar no banco de dados login e password e se a sessão existe.
Também em sua página de login nos valores recebidos do campo de login e senha filtrar caracteres especiais como aspas que poderiam criar furos de segurança.

Por fim, criar critérios para definir suas senhas, e nunca carrega-las para dentro de uma variavel em sessão ao invés disso criar uma hash com sha256 com php e sempre comparar a hash no banco de dados.

Essa é uma pergunta muito ampla sobre segurança se houver dúvidas não hesite em postar.

Abraços.