# Inibindo acesso pela URL

Tags: php

Quero saber se essa maneira esta correta:

pagina inibida

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
  session_destroy();
  header("Location: login.php"); exit;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Doidao</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> HELLO </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

código que verifica o login

```
<?php
include_once("conexao.php");
session_start();

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];



$result = "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `usuario` = '$usuario' AND `senha`= '$senha'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);
if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0 )
{
$_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
$_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
echo "<script>alert('Seja bem-vindo $usuario, conhecimento não é crime. ATT: Marcos.');</script>";
echo'<script>window.location="index.php";</script>';
}
else{
    unset ($_SESSION['usuario']);
    unset ($_SESSION['senha']);
  echo "<script>alert('Login ou senha incorretos !');</script>";
  echo'<script>window.location="login.php";</script>';


    }

?>
```

Comment: O que você quer dizer, quando diz: `Inibindo acesso pela URL` ?

Comment: Deixando a pagina como acesso restrito, acesso apenas via login.

Comment: Do jeito que está não está funcionando ?

Comment: Sim esta, mais queria saber se essa é uma maneira correta.

Comment: Então aqui tem a resposta que você procura: [Bloquear acesso de pagina PHP pela URL | Duvida sobre segurança das mesmas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/219744/60376)...  Vou sinalizar pra fechar essa pergunta.

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza creio que esta seria  melhor https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3571/qual-a-melhor-maneira-de-criar-um-sistema-de-login-com-php

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento bem melhor, eu vou só criando uma lista aqui pra achar mais rápido.